# Singleton Kotlin object method is not getting called, anyone know why?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, broadcastreceiver

please see image attached for the code. Basically, I have a singleton object in android I am trying to call methods on, but in my on receive code, the methods compile, but they wont log their messages in the log, so they are not getting called, or I am missing something. Does anyone know why?[image: code]

Comment: Don't take images of code.  Post the actual code as text.  This is a pain in the neck to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **shouldn't** create an instance of an object. Object is singleton in kotlin.

You must use it like Static class in java like below:

```
AlarmTone.[your function name]
```

Comment: would you know the best way to call a method in my singleton from a notification action button?